# Laravel 5.5 seeder really slow

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to seed a test database with a largish number of hits to test my dashboard metrics displays. So I want to generate the 25k hits, and associate them with a random `Post` from the database so that the data will be consistent.

I initially tried to grab a random `Post` in the `HitFactory` class, but this was really, really slow (like hours to generate several thousand hits). So then I moved the random part out into the seeder class, and made the call only once to minimize the DB hits, thinking this would speed it up considerably. But it didn't-- it still takes at least 5-10 seconds to create a single `Hit` object.

I'm not sure how this is possible-- is there an optimization I'm missing? Note that I can't just generate a random int between 1 - x and use that as the linked `Post`, since I'm using UUID style IDs for the `posts` table.

Here's the seeder that takes so long to run:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class HitsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {

        $posts = App\Post::all();

        $i = 0;

        while ($i <= 25000) {
            $post = $posts->random();
            factory(App\Hit::class)->create(
                [
                    'post_key' => $post->post_key,
                    'subject_code' => $post->subject_code,
                    'subject_id' => $post->subject_id,
                ]
            );
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I also tried just generating a random int between 1-500 in the `HitsTableSeeder` and using that as the index of the `$posts` collection to eliminate the `random()` call entirely. It's still slower than I can believe.

```
    while ($i <= 25000) {
        $t = rand(0, 500);
        $post = $posts[$t];
```

Comment: Is it only me or you never increment `$i` inside of your `while` loop in `HitsTableSeeder`?

Comment: You're, right, and I fixed that, but it's not related to the issue

Comment: Move that expensive creation code from loop and use loop just to form appropriate array for insertion. Also, inserting 25k rows at once would be overload and you should probably use `chunk()` method to split that huge array in smaller portions.

Comment: @Tpojka-- even if it's outside the loop the `create` will still need to be called 25k times, won't it

Comment: That is why you should use chunk method and split it into let's say 100 rows or depending how much data is there. You should test it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just posting this in case it can help anyone in the future. I ran into a similar problem with extremely slow inserts. If you are using MySQL, try using database transactions. In your case, manually start the transaction before your while loop and commit the transaction afterward. Apparently, the MySQL engine will commit each insert individually (adding overhead that is noticeable with large inserts) if you do not manually start and commit a transaction for the entire group (or chunks if you prefer). I saw enormous performance gains after doing this. Way more than just chunking, which actually didn't help in terms of performance in my case. Something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class HitsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {

        $posts = App\Post::all();

        $i = 0;

        DB::beginTransaction();

        while ($i <= 25000) {
            $post = $posts->random();
            factory(App\Hit::class)->create(
                [
                    'post_key' => $post->post_key,
                    'subject_code' => $post->subject_code,
                    'subject_id' => $post->subject_id,
                ]
            );
        }

        DB::commit();
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Just a note, I actually haven't tried this with factories yet, only with regular inserts (like with Model::create() for example). Hopefully it helps, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: You forgot to increment the $i, so this would cause an infinite loop/timeout;

`DB::commit();`

to:
`$i++;
DB::commit();
`

Answer (score 0):

Try first `make`ing the `Hit` instances and then chunk those into batches the size of `$posts->count()`:

```
$posts = App\Post::all();
$n = $posts->toArray();
$m = 25000;
$c = $posts->count();

factory(App\Hit::class, $m)->make()->chunk($c, function ($hits) use ($n) {
    foreach ($hits as $i => $hit) {
        $hit->fill([
            'post_key' => $n[$i]['post_key'],
            'subject_code' => $n[$i]['subject_code'],
            'subject_id' => $n[$i]['subject_id']
        ]);
        $hit->save();
    }
});
```

This would give you  an even dispersment of `Hit` records to `Posts`. If you wanted a more random weight you could use [array_random](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-random) to shuffle the posts within the inner `$hits` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = App\Post::orderBy('id')->take(25000)->chunk(250, function ($posts) {
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        //
    }
});
```

Just to be sure that you're not retrieving all the records at once and to chunk them into 250 per query to save memory.
However try using `$faker` create this factory inside the factory directory.

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Post::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'post_key' => $faker->name,
        'subject_code' => $faker->address,
        'subject_id' => $faker->numberBetween(1,25000)/* or either make it auto increment or loop on a counter */,
    ];
});
```

Now inside the seeder run method just call:

```
factory(App\Post::class, 25000)->create();
```